# simple html dom extracting table by its id

Tags: php, jquery, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple html dom in php to extract a table depending on its id. I have done this without any issues when the id doesn't involve any characters like hyphens(-). I suspect it is due to a hyphen because I used the same code with an id with no hyphens and no trouble receiving the data. The data I want to extract is also in a tab that is hidden, does this effect the process?

**Here is my code**

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

//Insert the url you want to extract data from
$html = file_get_html('http://espnfc.com/team/_/id/359/arsenal?cc=5739');

$i = 0;
$dataInTable = true;

while($dataInTable){

    if($html->find('div[id=ui-tabs-1] table tbody', 0)->children(0)->children($i)){

            for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){

                if($html->find('div[id=ui-tabs-1] table tbody', 0)->children(0)->children($i)->children($j)){
                    $gk[] = $html->find('div[id=ui-tabs-1] table tbody', 0)->children(0)->children($i)->children($j)->plaintext;
                }else{
                $dataInTable = false;
                }
            }

            //else if nothing is in the next cell return false.
        }else{
            $dataInTable = false;
        }


    $i+=2;
}
var_dump($gk);

?>
```

**Here is the HTML content**
[image]

Comment: Try enclose `id` in quotes

Comment: tried and didn't work

Comment: Does simple_html_dom support the id selector? `#ui-tabs-1`

Comment: @user3210416 I don't see it (quoted id value) in your code

Comment: I tried and in the simple html dom documentation they don't use quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a look at the source(not via dev-tools, use browser->viewsource) of  http://espnfc.com/team/_/id/359/arsenal?cc=5739 you'll not see anything with the ID `ui-tabs-1`

This element has been created via javascript(I guess jQueryUI-tabs)

`simple_html_dom` parses HTML but did not evaluate javascript, so the answer is:

**You can't select this element**

Comment: Can you advise if there is a way to get the data

Comment: I don't know which data exactly you like to access. The initial data(for the G-tab) are in the source, the ID of the element is a simple `G` . The data for the other tabs will be requested on demand via AJAX . But instead of scraping the data from the sourcecode you should look if there is an API available. I'm sure when it's legal to use the data they have an API(I'm also sure that when there isn't an API it's not legal)

Comment: I check for API's but I'm sure it is legal it is not against the law to data scrape especially factual data. Thank Dr

Comment: Of course you can select it, you just need to find another way :)